# How to manipulate shell during make?

Tags: shell, makefile

In short, I have a makefile which creates vfat file system using `make` as a part of build process.
It has working lines like

```
mcopy -i $@.boot $(STAGING_DIR_IMAGE)/$(DEVICE_NAME)-boot.scr ::boot.scr
```

I want to add 2 files to same filesystem at build time, with content like `param=prefix-[random]`.

```
TMP_HOSTNAME_PART=$( shell eval 'tr -dc A-Z </dev/urandom | head -c6' )
echo "kernel.hostname=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::hostname.txt
echo "ServerName=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::vhusbd.ini
undefine TMP_HOSTNAME_PART
```

Currently as result I get those files with empty data after `=` symbol, like

```
kernel.hostname=
ServerName=
```

Could you please help me understanding what is going wrong and help me correcting syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be looking for

```
target:
    TMP_HOSTNAME_PART=$$(tr -dc A-Z </dev/urandom | head -c6)\
     && echo "kernel.hostname=OPIZVH-$$TMP_HOSTNAME_PART" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::hostname.txt\
     && echo "ServerName=OPIZVH-$$TMP_HOSTNAME_PART" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::vhusbd.ini
```

Notice how this is a single logical line of shell script, executed by the shell; the dollar signs need to be doubled in order to prevent `make` from evaluating them where it shouldn't. There is no need to `unset` (let alone `undefine`) anything at the end, because the shell variable is only defined inside the shell instance which stops executing at the end of this logical line.

There is a GNU `make` extension `.ONESHELL` which evaluates multiple logical lines in a recipe in the same shell instance; but this approach should be portable to any reasonably standard `make`.

Your code seemed to attempt to use `make` syntax in the middle of a shell script snippet, which is a common beginner mistake. As a rough rule of thumb, `make` syntax is useful and correct while the `makefile` is being parsed, whereas individual recipes should mainly use shell syntax (though of course it's correct and useful to use `make` variable substitutions etc to interpolate a string into the recipe at parse time, for example). The [Stack Overflow `makefile` tag info page](/tags/makefile/info) has more information about this and several other common FAQs.

Comment: Note that Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces, so you won't be able to copy/paste this code directly.

Answer (score -1):

Is

```
TMP_HOSTNAME_PART=$( shell eval 'tr -dc A-Z </dev/urandom | head -c6' )
echo "kernel.hostname=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::hostname.txt
echo "ServerName=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::vhusbd.ini
undefine TMP_HOSTNAME_PART
```

within a make rule like:

```
all:
    TMP_HOSTNAME_PART=$( shell eval 'tr -dc A-Z </dev/urandom | head -c6' )
    echo "kernel.hostname=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::hostname.txt
    echo "ServerName=OPIZVH-$(TMP_HOSTNAME_PART)" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::vhusbd.ini
    undefine TMP_HOSTNAME_PART
```

If so then you have created a shell variable `TMP_HOSTNAME_PART` and not a make variable. To access shell variables you need to use double dollar `$$` since dollar is a make special char. Also it looks like you are using a make subshell with a similar issue `$( do shell stuff )`, then also needs to be double dollar. So maybe you need something like:

```
all:
    TMP_HOSTNAME_PART=$$( shell eval 'tr -dc A-Z </dev/urandom | head -c6' ); \
    echo "kernel.hostname=OPIZVH-$$TMP_HOSTNAME_PART" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::hostname.txt; \
    echo "ServerName=OPIZVH-$$TMP_HOSTNAME_PART" | mcopy -i $@.boot - ::vhusbd.ini; \
    undefine TMP_HOSTNAME_PART
```

But it is difficult to tell without more of the makefile to look at.

Update - also you need the line continuation so that your shell variables are still accessable as triplee pointed out

Comment: Individual recipe lines execute in separate subshells, so the variable will no longer be defined in tho line where you are trying to use it. You can work around this by using `.ONESHELL` or by merging these separate physical lines into one logical line with `;\ ` at the end of each except the last.

Comment: Using `$(shell ...)` in a line which is already using the shell is weird and confusing. You probably want `$$(...)` instead, not `$$(shell eval ...)` (unless you have a shell command called `shell` which you want the subshell to execute; but surely you don't, here).

Comment: @tripleee yes I agree - but this is not my code :o - I am just suggesting that OP needs to be using double (`$$`) for shell vars. But good point about continuing the line - that is also required, updated